# Is it correct for a HTTP app to accept a query string containing unencoded special chars and fail for an equivalent URL with special chars encoded?

Tags: url, url-encoding

I've encountered a situation whereby a `GET` request for a URL where the query string contains unencoded special characters returns `200 OK` for the URL as-is but returns a `400 Bad Request` when the special characters are url-encoded.

A simplified example of such a URL is: `http://example.com/??foo/bar+foobar`

Note the double question mark such that the entire query string is a single key-value pair with a null value.

URL-encoding the query string key gives us: `http://example.com/?%3Ffoo%2Fbar+foobar`

A `GET` request for this URL containing encoded characters will return `400 Bad Request`.

The application handling these URLs (a third party I don't control) appears to not like the query string key to contain url-encoded equivalents of non-alphanumeric characters.

I was under the assumption that `http://example.com/??foo/bar+foobar` and `http://example.com/?%3Ffoo%2Fbar+foobar` should be equivalent and consequently interchangeable. This may be an invalid assumption.

Are these two URLs equivalent and consequently interchangable?

Is it the application that handles these URLs at fault for not treating these URLs as equivalent or is it my application, which is applying url-encoding to query string keys and values, at fault for applying such encoding?